# Update quote totals based on the VAT rate

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax

In the checkout in the `country_id` dropdown, I have 2 countries: FR and BE.
For FR I have a VAT percentage of 20% and for BE I have 21%.

My goal is to update the tax amount in the checkout.

When I switch countries I triggered an ajax request:

```
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();

        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId);
        if ($countryId === 'BE') {
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                   // do smth 
            }
        }
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

I also made this observer, listening to this event: `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` :

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $countryId = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
    if ((string)$countryId === 'BE'){
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $product->setTaxClassId(14);  //14 is my Product Tax Class ID 
        }
    }
}
```

My product includes the TAX. Right now, when I switch to BE, I m getting this:
[image]

My grand and subtotals contain the product price including tax + the Tax, not sure why?

Do you have any idea about how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the foreach of the execute function as :

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $product->setTaxClassId(14);
    $item->setPrice($item->getPrice())
         ->setSpecial($item->getPrice());
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($item->getPrice())
         ->setOriginalPrice($item->getPrice())
         ->save();
}
```

Make the changes according to the *country_code* and change the *tax_class_id* according to your need.